# execute script on remote machine from jump host without password prompt

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have a script *fixa.sh* deployed in all my client machine. I want to run this script from my jump host through a for loop script. Script on execution, prompts for sudo password. How can i make it as non interactive execution on jump host just be reading the password while executing.

I know if it is a sudo command i can make execute like

```
echo -n password: 
read -s password
ssh -t hostname 'echo $password | sudo -s <Command>'
```

But not sure how can i make the same way to execute script.

Comment: You can not echo the password into `sudo`/`su` without doing a security critical change first, see https://superuser.com/questions/119376/bash-su-script-giving-an-error-standard-in-must-be-a-tty

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with compromising the security a little, change the sudoers rule such that it doesn't prompt for password.